# can't add new elements to my table

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm working on a simple chat page where a user writes his name and his message and clicks on a submit button that redirects him to the same form page where now he can see his message just under the form, note that the message are ordered by latest.

My problem is that when I for example write a name and a message in my page and click on send nothing appears and nothing is added to my table. However, when I do it manually ( from phpmyadmin ) the message appears.

I think there is something wrong in my sql queries but I wasn't able to find it, I know seek your help to show me what's wrong and how to correct it please.

My code is separated in two files: chat.php and chat_post.php.

**chat.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mini chat</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: grey;
        }
        div#f, p{
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        input#mbox{
            height: 300px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <p>Bienvenue à la page de chat</p>

        <div id="f">
        <form method="POST" action="chat_post.php">
            pseudo : <br>
            <input type="text" name="pseudo" ><br><br>
            message : <br>
            <input type="text" name="message" id="mbox" ><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="envoyer">
        </form>
        </div>

        <?php 
            try{
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=learn','root','');
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
            }

            $a=$db->query('SELECT pseudo,message FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10');
            while ($b=$a->fetch()) {
                echo '<p>'.htmlspecialchars($b['pseudo']).' : '.htmlspecialchars($b['message']).'</p>';
            }
            $a->closeCursor();  
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**chat_post.php :**

```
<?php 

try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=learn','root','');
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
if (isset($_POST['pseudo']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $a = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO chat(id,pseudo,message) VALUES(pseudo,message)');
    $a ->execute(array('pseudo' =>$_POST['pseudo'],'message' => $_POST['message']));
    header('Location : chat.php');
    echo "message added";
}




 ?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `INSERT INTO chat(id,pseudo,message) VALUES(pseudo,message)` look at this carefully. (1,2,3) - (1,2). Had you checked for errors, it would have thrown you something about it.

Comment: `header('Location :` and that's another error. There should not be a space between `Location` and the colon.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the id is auto-incremented so what should I write instead of nothing ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO chat(id,pseudo,message) VALUES('', :pseudo,:message)` and missing `:` for both.

Comment: then `header('Location :` to `header('Location:`

Comment: what I wrote should basically fix all this, but you can't use header and echo, remove the echo.

Comment: Or, one could write the query like so: `INSERT INTO chat(pseudo,message) VALUES(:pseudo, :message)`

Comment: ^ yeah that too. They have the choice from either.

Comment: @Blueberry Welcome to [so], to thank people for their help you can upvote their answer and mark it if the solution was satisfactory.

Comment: @Blueberry A code improvement would be in `chat_post.php`, move the code after your `try` block inside of it, after your `$db = ..`. It would have [raised an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818279/cant-add-new-elements-to-my-table#comment72748302_42818279) and if it did, stay on the page instead of going back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated:

```
INSERT INTO chat(id,pseudo,message) VALUES(pseudo,message)
```

is missing an argument in the values and the missing colons.

```
INSERT INTO chat(id,pseudo,message) VALUES('', :pseudo, :message)
```

Or, as stated by Xorifelse

```
INSERT INTO chat(pseudo,message) VALUES(:pseudo, :message)
```

both will work.

and the extra space between `Location` and the colon need to be removed.

```
header('Location : chat.php');
                ^ right there
```

to

```
header('Location: chat.php');
exit;
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Remove the echo also and add an exit to it to prevent further execution.

Reference links to check for errors:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Reference for PDO's prepared statements:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php